# Error in #C- the code print all time "error" in visual studio

Tags: c, compiler-errors, printf

I have a question in #c.

the code print all time "error" .

I try to do debugging but i didnt succeeded.
The code should not enter the condition and it does enter the condition. What is the problem?

the code is:

```
int main()
{
    char name[10];
    int number_cores = 0, size = 0, grade = 0;
    float avarge = 0.0, sum = 0.0;
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    FILE *fwrite = NULL;
    int i;
    fp = fopen("grades.txt", "r");
    if (fp)
    {
        printf("error");
        return 0;
    }
    fwrite = fopen("averages.txt", "w");
    if (fwrite)
    {
        printf("error");
        return 0;
    }
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", name);
        fprintf(fwrite,"%s:", name);
        fscanf(fp,"%d", &number_cores);
        sum = 0, grade = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < number_cores; i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &grade);
            sum += grade;
        }
        avarge = (sum / number_cores);
        fprintf(fwrite, "%f\n",avarge);
    }
    fclose(fwrite);
    fclose(fp);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Not sure it's your problem, but see [Why is `while( !feof(file) )` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941)

Comment: Best to not name a variable `fwrite` since that is a name used by the standard library. `if (fwrite)` checks if the file pointer is not NULL which it wouldn't be if the file was successfully opened. Perhaps you want `if (!fwrite)` so the error only happens when the file isn't opened? Same issue with `fp` earlier.

Comment: What is "#C"?  Your code looks like C, so you probably didn't mean C#.  (But if it was supposed to be a hashtag, this here is Stack Overflow, not Twitter. :-) )

Comment: `perror` is your friend. Use it.

Answer (score 3):

You are checking for errors from `fopen` incorrectly. These functions return `NULL` on failure or valid pointers on success. `if(fp)` checks if `fp` is such a valid pointer, but you're using it as an error indication which causes 'error' to be printed to standard output.

What platform are you writing for? POSIX and Windows both set `errno` when the standard I/O functions fail, so it's better to use `perror()` to print detailed error information to standard error.

As pointed out in the comments, you should not call a variable fwrite, since that clashes with the name of the standard I/O function (and you are using standard I/O functions here).